# Comma-Separated variable in foreach loop to xml rows in php script

Tags: php, arrays, xml, string, foreach

I am trying to make a loop that will output xml rows in the php script. The values come from comma separated variable like following:

```
$commaValues = '5773270,5778216';
$lubuvnaCommas = explode(',', $commaValues);

foreach($lubuvnaCommas as $row){
        $expected = $row;
        $destinations = "<cl_id>".$expected."</cl_id>";
    }
```

the destination variable should be outputted in the defined xml structure in my script like following:

```
$xml ='
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <destinations>
   '.$destinations.'
   </destinations>;
```

this means the final output of the xml data should look like following:

```
$xml ='
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <destinations>
   <cl_id>5773270</cl_id>
   <cl_id>5778216</cl_id>
   </destinations>';
```

I tried many options, i feel there is something missing in my loop that doesn't output a loop of xml data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine:

```
$commaValues = '5773270,5778216';
$lubuvnaCommas = explode(',', $commaValues);
$destinations = '';

foreach($lubuvnaCommas as $row){
    // Concatenate current value with previous ones
    $destinations .= "<cl_id>".$row."</cl_id>";
}

$xml ='
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <destinations>
   '.$destinations.'
   </destinations>';
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/V6EMA).

Comment: i was stuck for many hours on this. now you solved it, appreciate it. Thanks dear

Comment: I know OP accepted this answer, but can you please `echo $xml` and post the output? For some reason, I'm not getting the expected output presented in the question.

Comment: Added a fiddle.